# PHP - filename calls function on different script, get filename from script containing function

Tags: php, filenames, require

**fileA.php:** requires function.inc.php and uses `x()` from that include file

**fileB.php:** requires fileA.php *User invokes fileB.php to get fileA.php*

**function.inc.php:** `function x()` - returns filename that invoked it

What is the PHP server variable or whatever that gets the name of fileA.php from *within function.inc.php*?

- Usecase - function x() could be a `mysql_query() or die(mail( {info about error as well as which file caused it} )`

based on answer below - this works:

`function  x($q){ 
mysql_query($q) or die(mail('yourself@example.com,'error  @ '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] , serialize(debug_backtrace()) . "\n\n".mysql_error()));
}`

---

- for the person who voted this down - could you provide a better idea/solution for the function trace above?

Comment: What is the UseCase for your problem. It sounds fishy to me.

Comment: for the person who voted this down - could you provide a better idea/solution for the function trace above?

Comment: The downvote isn't from me, but I still don't understand why you need this?

Comment: well, if there's any mysql_error, it's better to have it be logged or emailed and to have the *source* that generated it be recorded, as well. the latter part was the crux of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't one.  You could traverse the output of [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to find it.